# What is the right thing to do with an old cross-posted question?

Tags: discussion, support

I just found this question: [How to remove the thumbnail frame in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907407/how-to-remove-the-thumbnail-frame-in-nautilus) posted almost a year ago. Then noticed OP has posted an [identical question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360415/how-to-remove-the-thumbnail-frame-in-nautilus) at U&L which got an answer with a positive score. The question is technically on-topic at both sites IMO, but I believe it's [against SE policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

What is the right course of action here? I used to think flagging for moderator's attention is the right way to deal with these questions, but my last such flag was declined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, flag it for mod attention, giving the link of the cross post. You can flag it on either of the two sites. If you want to be extra nice and get brownie points, let us know that one of the two questions has an answer, that makes it easier to know which one to close or delete.

In this case, since it was already answered on U&L and had no answers here, I deleted the one from AU. Thanks!